# What is the use of the hackers.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt, html5boilerplate

### First

No I am not asking you to teach me hacking, I am just curious about this file and its content.

### My journey

When I dived into the new HTML5 Boilerplate I came accross the humans.txt. I googled for it and I came at this site http://humanstxt.org/.

Immediately my attention went to this picture:

[image: Where is it located]

Do I read this correctly? `Hackers.txt`?

So I resumed my journey in google and stopped at [this articles](http://www.textfiles.com/news/hackers.txt)

When I started reading this I had the feeling that its about the difference between Hackers and Crackers. Later I got the feeling that I'm might be wrong and that this place is that this hackers.txt file is a sort of guestbook for hackers?

Also other examples about hackers.txt files I found [here](http://www.elite-hackers.com/textfiles)

Some files contain code, others have just hurtfull information.

Now I'm realy confused, guestbook, hack tutorials or just history?

### Question

What is the use of this hackers.txt file?

Comment: FWIW: http://mrkiffie.com/blog/code/hackers-txt/ and http://www.elladodelmal.com/2011/02/hackerstxt.html (not in English)

Comment: @unor I've read them yes. Mr Kiffie's conclusion is: `I haven’t been able to find any standard for a hackers.txt file` So that has no use, the other is in spanish.. Still thanks! :)

Comment: This comment from from https://twitter.com/hackerstxt is interesting too:
«Let hackers know where to discretely report vulnerabilities with /hackers.txt»

Comment: It's where you put the [script to Hackers](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/hackers.txt).

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I've posted a definitive, fact-based (and fact-checkable) answer. If it pleases you, feel free to mark it as accepted! ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR:

To quote from [RFC-9116](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9116) "**A File Format to Aid in Security Vulnerability Disclosure**" (published 2022-04-27):

> When security vulnerabilities are discovered by researchers, proper reporting channels are often lacking. As a result, vulnerabilities may be left unreported. This document defines a machine-parsable format ("security.txt") to help organizations describe their vulnerability disclosure practices to make it easier for researchers to report vulnerabilities.

This `security.txt` file was previously known as **`hackers.txt`**

---

## The Full Story

Commonly known as Eduardo Vela, [Eduardo A. Vela Nava](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eduardovela/) (or <kbd>sirdarckcat</kbd> on [Github](https://github.com/sirdarckcat/) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/sirdarckcat/)) has been a Security Engineer at Google since 2010. (He currently has the role of Product Security Response Team Lead).

As other security experts before him, he pondered the issue of effectively communicating the details of a site's vulnerability reward program to [white hat hackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security))/[pen-testers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test).

One specific such person is [Chema Alonso](https://www.linkedin.com/in/chemaalonso/) (also on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/chemaalonso)).

He is well-known enough to warrant [a Spanish Wikipedia entry](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chema_Alonso)

Between 2005 and 2011 Alonso was awarded the Microsoft Most Valuable Professional Award for Enterprise Security **6 years in a row**. That should tell you something about his "skillz".

---

**On February 3rd 2011** Alonso wrote about his frustrations regarding the topic of communication between the administrators and/or developers of a site and hackers.

[image: Screenshot of Alonso's hackers.txt blog-post]

He proposes [a similar initiative as `humans.txt` but for hackers](http://www.elladodelmal.com/2011/02/hackerstxt.html). As he mentions this `hackers.txt` initiative in his blog-post.

---

**In April 2011** The humanstxt.org website got [a new design](https://web.archive.org/web/20110405074122/http://humanstxt.org:80/) which includes the image which mentions the `hackers.txt` file.

At this point, I must sadly submit to conjecture, but... consider:

- The [team behind `humans.txt`](http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt) are all from Spain (mostly Barcelona)
- At this point Alonso is already quite well known in the Spanish developer community

Would it be such a far stretch to imagine that they got to know of each other's efforts?

---

**On May 14th 2014** Vela, already working at Google, [commented on a blog-post by Alonso](http://www.elladodelmal.com/2014/05/gmail-borraste-en-google-pero-te-quedan.html). It is most likely that they had further contact in a professional setting. Whether or not thay extively shared their idea's regarding anything related to `hackers.txt` is unknown.

---

**On July 6th 2017** Vela posted a question to this extent on twitter:

[image: Screenshot of the Twitter post by Eduardo Vela]

> How about we create a /hackers.txt that says whether something is in scope or not of a vulnerability reward program and where to report it?

Subsequently, an empty git repository was created for [hackerstxt.org on github](https://github.com/sirdarckcat/hackerstxt.org/)
and [an email thread was opened at Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hackerstxt) to discuss this idea further.

---

**On August 13 2017**, [Edwin Foudil](https://edoverflow.com/) (or <kbd>EdOverflow</kbd> on [Github](https://github.com/EdOverflow) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/EdOverflow)) created a git repository for [`security.txt` on Github](https://github.com/securitytxt/security-txt) and responded to the mailing list:

> I have published a similar project to the one being discussed in this group (https://github.com/EdOverflow/security-txt) and would love to get some of your feedback and ideas.
>
> The project is the equivalent of robots.txt, but for defining a security policy. Companies can add a security.txt to their website and define clear guidelines of what security researchers must do when they discover a security issue. security.txt also allows bug bounty programs to add their scope there. security.txt uses a similar syntax to robots.txt, which should make it easier for machines to parse.

He was, in part, inspired by an open-source project he was working on at the time called [GratiPay](https://github.com/gratipay/gratipay.com). GratiPay had [a `SECURITY.txt` file since 2013](https://github.com/gratipay/gratipay.com/blob/7136d3be990bcd4e34837c1b163daf1a28538af1/www/security.txt).

His inspiration also drew from the `SECURITY.md` files that more and more open-source projects were adding to their repositories.

---

**On September 10th 2017**, Foudil submitted a first [draft for `security.txt`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-foudil-securitytxt) to the [Internet Engineering Task Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force).

[image]

---

**On September 14th 2017** Alonso wrote [a blog post](http://www.elladodelmal.com/2017/09/securitytxt-un-draft-del-ietf-para-mi.html) with the title (translated from Spanish) "Security.TXT an IETF draft for my Hackers.TXT".

Beyond the title, Alonso does not allude to the fact that his 2011 idea was the origin of the draft but he does state his approval of the effort.

---

**On February 3rd 2018**, the mail group was informed to concede to `security.txt` and Vela tweeted that [Google had already implemented one](https://twitter.com/sirdarckcat/status/959585939822710786).

---

**On April 27th 2022**, after [various drafts](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9116/) RFC-9116 was published. The `security.txt` is now an official standard!

[image: history of RFC-9116]

---

### Further information

Details and a [nifty](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nifty) tool to generate your own `security.txt` can be found at
**https://securitytxt.org/**

[image: Screenshot of the securitytxt.org website]

### Adoptation

Even though the RFC is still in draft, the standard is already being adopted quite well by major players on the web.

Besides the [security.txt at Google](https://www.google.com/.well-known/security.txt), there is also one on the website of:

- [1password](https://1password.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- bit.ly - http://bit.ly/security.txt (can't be linked because [StackOverflow blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts))
- [CERT NZ](https://www.cert.govt.nz/.well-known/security.txt)
- [DailyMotion](https://www.dailymotion.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [Github](https://github.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/.well-known/security.txt)
- [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/.well-known/security.txt)
- [Open SSL](https://www.openssl.org/.well-known/security.txt)
- [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/.well-known/security.txt)

(Feel free to add more from *well-known* sites, if you find 'm)

Answer (score 9):

The way I see things:

- `robots.txt` contains information and instructions for robots (so it should be read/used by web crawlers, spiders and other kind of bots)
- `humans.txt` contains useful information to be consumed by humans, according to http://humanstxt.org/
- `hackers.txt` should be targeted towards hackers, so it should contain any information the site owner might want to transmit to a hacker, as Ze'ev [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358794/246645). I don't think this should be a place for hackers to write anything, but rather to get information from the site owner (perhaps on how to report vulnerabilities, as others suggested).

Answer (score 6):

As with `humans.txt`, there also seems to be a `hackers.txt` site at [http://www.hackerstxt.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140123101805/http://www.hackerstxt.org/). I'm not sure if someone has set the site up as a joke or not, but it links to a blog post on someone's Blogger site.

The post rambles on a bit (I put it through Google Translate) about the poster's history as a 'hacker'. Anyway, towards the end the writer says:

> therefore believe we should promote an initiative type hackers.txt , in which managers leave us a message to potential "aliens who are good" that makes it clear they will do managers receive a report of a vulnerability in your site. I've been circling this , the truth is that it is difficult to finish shaping, because perhaps some "alien who is not so good" , type Brainiac , take a free hand to brush a site, or the "good board administrator" , decide to change your mind and Liem, but I think we should be able to do something, I dunno, maybe having Jon Jonz , or perhaps thinking about how to write that file hackers.txt . How do you see it? Greetings Evil!

So I assume that the poster wants to start a sort of `hackers.txt` standard in the vein of `humans.txt`, but hasn't finished it off, or hasn't gotten it into the English speaking world.

Digging around, the Blogger site seems to be owned by a guy called Chema Alonso, who must be fairly reputable in the world of Spanish programmers as he has about 35k Twitter followers (https://twitter.com/chemaalonso). He seems to work for a company called ElevenPaths (http://elevenpaths.com/), which says that it's driving "radical innovation in security product development". A quick Whois check shows that the `hackerstxt.org` domain is registered by someone in Madrid, so I would assume it's Alonso.

The `.txt` file over at http://www.textfiles.com/news/hackers.txt, which has been refered to by some of the other answers in this thread, doesn't seem to have anything to do with the `hackers.txt` reference over at http://humanstxt.org/, and neither do most other search results for 'hackers.txt'.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly a joke, but If humans.txt is for humans to read then maybe hackers.txt is a warning for hackers.

Like the notice you get when you SSH into some more public terminals.  "You are being watched... we will get you if you do anything bad..." That sort of thing.

If a hacker did compromise the site, the might notice the file, read it, realise you mean business and be scared away!

Interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is somewhat open, I think you are also expecting some assumptions, I write here (not in a comment) my opinion, but if it should be there, I'm sorry.

I think that the idea lying behind `humans.txt` (which I heard of before) is to make a new habit, new style or something like that. In fact, you can put a contact page, where all these data from `humans.txt` can be put. I think that `hackers.txt` could be also something like new style.

I suppose that hackers.txt was much earlier, maybe for 20 years, when www servers and popular web knowledge was poor, when using localhost Apache+PHP+MySQL was making you "a hacker", and if someone could access the file other than `index.html` (and linked pages from this), reading `hackers.txt` was some kind of prize, or maybe some kind of filter to show some information to "those who behold" (like [this one](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=OgZtkg6HIkRlLW756iRUm5NmF7Q&cid=GDDmhcLr_xk&s=&browser=Default#L0) perhaps).

Answer (score -1):

I think hackers.txt should contain notes on how the site owner would like for data to be used... E.g. "I don't mind if you scrape the movie listings, but please don't hot link out images in your app"